# Чередование Б и В

Tags: фонетика

Такие слова, как Babilon, Barbara во всех языках пишутся и читаются через Б, а у нас почему-то через В — Вавилон, Варвара. Я знаю, что, например, в испанском в некоторых случаях буква V читается как среднее между Б и В (у меня никогда так произнести не получалось))), но вообще это звуки даже не родственны. Как вышло, что у нас, вопреки всему, Б превратилось в В?

Answer (score 5):

Это происходит в словах заимствованных и Западом и нами с греческого языка. У греков буква "в", во времена Рима читалась как [б], а к моменту христианизации славян уже как [в]. Из-за этого и разница в произношении, связанная со временем заимствования слова с греческого.

Comment: А испанский-то тут причем?

Comment: @behemothus, испанский тут вроде как и ни причём. По крайней мере гугл-переводчик произносит на испанском "варвар" как бАрбаро.

Comment: Тогда Ваше объяснение как минимум не полное. 
Автор вопроса не ставит вопроса о Гугле, он спрашивает о некоем "родстве" звуков вообще. А Вы вы ему предлагаете "универсальный" ответ.

Comment: >он спрашивает о некоем "родстве" звуков вообще.

Мне кажется, автор вопроса спрашивает не "вообще", а конкретно почему в **русском языке** некоторые слова пишутся через "в", в то время как, *кое-где на Западе* :-) через "б".

Исходя из этого, я и свой ответ ему написал ниже.

Comment: @behemothus, у меня сложилось впечатление, что автор вопроса спрашивал не об этом, а испанский привёл в пример, лишь в качестве возможной наводки. В любом случае, достаточными знаниями, чтобы рассуждать об особенностях испанской и греческой фонетики я не обладаю.

Answer (score 3):

> Как вышло, что у нас, вопреки всему, Б превратилось в В?

Это не *у нас*, это *у них* :-)

**Восточная Римская Империя** или Второй Рим, уже после своего падения названный Византией. Там греческая буква "бета" произносилась как "вита", и соответственно древнегреческие слова с "б" там произносились с "в" . Пожалуй, самое могущественное и цивилизованное государство на тот исторический момент, когда начало складываться такое государство, как Киевская Русь.

Влияние Византии на культуру Руси было значительным. Как лет 100-200 тому назад всё копировали с Франции, так тогда копировали с Византии. Поэтому в русском языке так много греческих слов именно с византийским произношением, через "в", а не через "б". Например, *алфавит*, а не *алфабет*.

Comment: Кроме того, мне кажется, что в фонетиках разных языков есть склонности к определённым звукам (сочетаниям звуков). Так, например, некоторые казахи и узбеки произносят русское слово "верблюд" в варианте "берблюд".

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых. Что такое "неродственые" звуки? Никогда не сталкивался с подобным определением в отношении звуков. Есть понятие фонетической близости, но оно обычно выводится из фонетики конкретного языка, близкие в одном зыке звуки (З и Д в арабском, например) могут оказаться совсем не близкими в другом (русском).

Во-вторых, Эти два явления, совпадение V и Б в испанском и параллельность русского Б и западноевропейского Б в греческих других словах и некоторых никак друг с другом не связаны.

В отношении первого. Марк Из в целом дал ответ, утаив правда некоторые детали. 
Западноевропейские языки не заимствовали ничего из греческого напрямую. Романских (как и славянских) языков во времена Эллады не существовало, а германские еще не пришли в Европу. Нас самом деле почти все интересующие нас заимствования произошли из средневекового латинского не раньше XIV-XV веков, где едва ли не волевым порядком - язык уже был к тому моменту мертвым - было установлено чтение греческих слов через Б. Византия к тому моменту уже находилась в стадии упадка и прямые контакты Европы с ней были минимальны. Таким образом называть эти слова греческими без специальных оговорок неправильно.

Не все так просто и с заимствованиями в славянский. Скорее всего к моменту создания славянской азбуки греческая бета еще не стала современной витой, но находилось в пограничном состоянии. Смотрите, в кириллице (с глаголицей - вопрос сложный) последовательность букв строго следует греческому оригиналу, буквы для отсутствующих в греческом звуков помещены в конец. Единственное существенное исключение - В, которое следует сразу за Б. Вывод. Во-первых, греки различали эти звуки, во-вторых понимали что один "выводится" их другого. Поэтому, сдается мне, что и в этом случае выбор В для транслитерации греческих слов скорее некоторая условность, чем отражение реальности.

Теперь по поводу испанского. Я не знаю языка, но что касается фонетики - могу вбросить свои пять копеек.
Для начала - далеко не все диалекты смешивают эти звуки. Далее, b и v в литературном испанском (он же - кастильский или кастильянский) действительно совпадают, но звучат по-разному в зависимости от позиции. В начале слова перед гласными - это вполне себе русское Б, "нечто среднее" проявляется обычно перед согласными.

В сравнительно недавние времена в кастильском эти звуки звучали по-разному. Это можно заключить хотя бы из сравнения с португальским, отделившимся от испанского в XIV, кажется, веке. Там b и v различаются.

Причину такого перехода назвать не берусь (если здесь вообще уместно говорить о причине), хотя подозреваю, что это может быть как-то связано с общей тенденцией добавления "энергетики" в испанский: Т часто переходит в Д, Р звучит раскатисто даже по сравнению с итальянским, G и J звучат как смычный Х (хотя и по-разному) проч.
Ни щелевой, ни велярный V никак не сделаешь звучащим более энергично, зато близкий к нему взрывной B вполне это позволяет.

В близости В и V легко убедиться. Произнесите "V" не вытягивая и не округляя губ. 
Насколько понимаю что-то очень похожее и произносят испанцы в соответствующих позициях.

Comment: > Романских ... языков во времена Эллады
> не существовало

Латинский относится к романским языкам.

> заимствования произошли из
> средневекового латинского не раньше
> XIV-XV веков, где едва ли не волевым
> порядком - язык уже был к тому моменту
> мертвым - было установлено чтение
> греческих слов через Б

В латинский, а через него распространилось по остальной Европе, все эти слова были заимствованы гораздо раньше, когда звука [в] в латинском, скорей всего, не было вовсе. Учитывая, что латинское "b" читалось всегда как [б], особых вариантов у средневековых чтецов и не было.

Comment: >Латинский относится к романским языкам. 
Я про современные латинские. Там по контексту очевидно.

>когда звука [в] в латинском, скорей всего, не было вовсе.  

Это когда ж такое было? До появления у латинян алфавита, что ли? 
Ну ясно же что V введена в латинский алфавит для обозначения латинского звука, а не греческого, где его просто не было. 
Посмотрите исьторию латинского алфавита. Там всего три изменения. 
Переход звучания С (греческой гаммы) из Г в К, утрата в связи с этим К и восстановление звука для G как "С с диакритикой". Всё остальное - неизменно или несущественно.

Comment: А главное - какой свет это предположение проливает на всю историю зимствования? Только затуманивает.

ЗЫ Марк, ну что Вы ловите блох у меня в газу, а свои бревна не видите?

Comment: Вот цитата из вашей же ссылки на Вики: 

> Уже в новое время произошла
> дифференциация слоговых и неслоговых
> вариантов букв I и V (I/J и U/V).

Там же, в таблице, указано, что в классической латыни "V" произносилось как [uː]. Вообще "V" мог обозначать как гласные, так и полугласные фонемы (ū/ /u/ /w/), но все эти звуки от [б] очень далеки.

А уточнение это нужно, чтобы у людей читающих, ваш довольно интересный и в целом качественный ответ, не сложилось впечатление, что слова "варвар", "библия" и другие, появились в романских языках, только в эпоху Ренессанса.