# Чередование на письме звуков Б и В в русском языке

Tags: грамматика, морфология, фонетика, чередования

Приведите, пожалуйста, примеры пар русских слов с чередованием Б-В (или обратно).

Comment: В письменной речи используются буквы, а звуки относятся к произношению.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 2):

В современном русском литературном языке **такого чередования согласных нет**.

Есть, например, чередования [б]//[бл'] (лю**б**овь — лю**бл**ю), [в]//[вл'] (пла**в**ать — спла**вл**ять), но [б]//[в] — нет.

Также интересны случаи, когда некоторые заимствования по-разному отобразились в разных языках, например: рус. *алфа**в**ит* и англ. *alpha**b**et* (элфэ**б**эт). См. «[Чередование Б и В](https://rus.stackexchange.com/q/18100/178412)».

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Да, в современном русском таких чередований не стало. Но ведь когда-то они были!

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Из устаревших (недавно вышедших из употребления) можно вспомнить: 
Бурчать - Ворчать (Бурчало - Ворчало, Ворчун); 
Боршать - Ворчать;
Вороток - Бараток (кипяток);
Бред, бреда́ - Вред;
Борун - Говорун (от вор/чать); 
Бороной - Вороной (о лошади), и пр.

Comment: @АндрианКомнин простите, но, например, в _бред_ — _вред_ совсем нет чередования, это этимологически разнокорневые слова. Что вы называете чередованием?